# How to retrieve featured image url in a category view?

Tags: wordpress

I'm editing my theme's entry.php to replace a thumbnail with featured image of the post.

Wrote the following script:

```
echo $post->ID; //outputs 141
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID, array('100', '100'));
var_dump($feat_image);
```

Outputs: bool(false)

I just want to get the URL of featured image so I can style it under  tag myself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an image size set to 100x100px?
Can you try to pass 'thumbnail' instead of array('100', '100')?

Comment: Same with thumbnail parameter.